# Prefix matching in objective c

Tags: objective-c, c, cocoa, trie

I am using [objective-c implementation](https://github.com/nathanday/ndtrie#readme) of [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) for prefix matching but its taking huge memory (for 200k file paths its taking 600MB). can any one suggest me any alternative for prefix matching in objective-c.

```
NDMutableTrie *pathsTrie=[[NDMutableTrie alloc] init];
[pathsTrie addString:filepath]; //filepath is NSString
[pathsTrie containsObjectForKeyWithPrefix:pathForItem]
```

I have `NDMutableTrie`, which contain some file paths and i am checking a folder path with that `NDMutableTrie`.

Comment: What does "2lakhs file paths" mean? Please give us more information about what you are searching as well. Any reason not to use regex or simple string searches since 600MB of memory use is a problem?

Comment: Are you trying to match pathnames only or generic strings?

Answer (score 1):

You might try [OFTrie](http://www.omnigroup.com/company/developer/).

Comment: Please give me source code URL for OFTrie. https://nodeload.github.com/omnigroup/OmniGroup/zipball/master URL is not working.

Comment: I had to clone the git repository.  Here's the git [link](https://github.com/omnigroup/OmniGroup.git).

Comment: I found the whole framework pretty hard to get started with on iOS7 — I just want to use their trie and nothing else!

Answer (score 1):

The trie algorithm deliberately uses a sparse data structure to speed up searching. If this is using too much memory for you, you should consider an algorithm with more conservative memory use, for example storing the paths in an ordered array and discovering a match via a binary search (whether you use byte wise comparisons or regular expressions to do the actual matching), or you could put the whole lot into a database and find your matches via queries.